# Bootstrap grid remove space between divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show 2 divs side by side using bootstrap grid. The problem is I can't figure out how to collapse the empty pace between the divs so that their content shows side by side with no space between.

Normally I'd just float both divs left or set both to "display:inline-block" but I'm trying to use more modern techniques. Is this the correct usage for bootstrap grid or is it supposed to be more for displaying tabular data like display:table? If not what modern technique should I use in this case?

Float left (visual results I'm looking for):

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        Test Content 1
     </div>
     <div style="float:left; margin-left:10px;">
        Test Content 2
     </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap grid (empty space between content):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        Test Content 1
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
        Test Content 2
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since bootstrap 4 there is a `no-glutters` class, that will take care of this.
Just add it to the row class.

```
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        Test Content 1
     </div>
     <div class="col-xs-6">
        Test Content 2
     </div>
</div>
```

Here are more details about it in the bootstrap docs:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#no-gutters

Comment: Thank you, I had seen that answer earlier but didn’t realize it was specific to bootstrap 4. I’m working on pulling that down now, once I get it working I’ll mark you as the answer. Edit: is this the technique you would use to do this for a modern site? I see flexbox grids are an option in bootstrap 4 as well.

Comment: @mgmedick this is definitely the way to go with bootstrap. Of course, you can use the flexbox implementation as well, but if you are using bootstrap everything, that they provide a class for, is something that is valid and usable in modern development.
If you have a page, where you don't need that many bootstrap components, I would - personally - recommend to just go for the flexbox way to avoid the overhead, but that's just me. Bootstrap is perfectly fine and modern enough.